# Удаление сохранённой wifi точки через терминал

Tags: linux, wifi

1. Как удалить сохранённую wifi точку через терминал в Linux ? Как её забыть ?
2. Где хранятся эти wifi точки ? Т.е в каком текстовом файле ?

Comment: Зависит от того, какая программа используется. Навскидку варианты: wpa_supplicant, systemd-networkd, netctl, NetworkManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как подсказали в комментарии, зависит от того, какой демон отвечает у вас за автоматическую настройку беспроводных соединений, например:

- NetworkManager
- Wicd
- netctl
- ConnMan

Во многих дистрибутивах GNU/Linux за автоматическую настройку отвечает `NetworkManager`.

Если это так, тогда все системные соединения будут находиться в данной директории -
`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Для того, чтобы "забыть" соединение, нужно удалить одно из них (которое требуется).

В качестве напримера:
`sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Home`, где `Home` - это имя нужной сети.

После нужно перезагрузить демон:
`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

Comment: @stackflow Да, вы правильно заметили. Сейчас дополню ответ.